# Given a box of dimension $\sqrt{3}$ × $\sqrt{3}$ × $\sqrt{3}$ meters; Is the volume of this box "defined".

Tags: combinatorics, volume

Since $\sqrt{3}$ never terminates,there is no finite length ,breadth or height.
By this I mean you never end measuring  if you want to achieve extreme precision. Say you keep on measuring to get the correct length with a hypothetical instrument that is super precise.
So is the box volume defined? (or length for that matter)

I am not confusing infinity with irrational here.

Infinity is like - i am trying to find the largest number and can never end my process of counting (just one example of infinity).
Similarly , here I am trying to find the exact length by measuring unit by unit and I cant reach the end, because the number is irrational.

One more interesting question which is related to this is , is the area of a square paper with $\sqrt{2}$ definite.

Please correct me if I am getting the whole idea of infinity wrong.

Comment: I don't understand why this question garnered so many downvotes when another question was asked a few before without so much as a thought and didn't receive any votes whatsoever.

Comment: This question had more to do with tools then with math. Tools have certain precision so yes it's impossible to measure exactly $\sqrt{3}$ m 100% confidently, but you know what else is. Measuring $1$ m 100% confidently.

Comment: You're throwing around a few words in ways that don't necessarily make sense. For example, in the first sentence, you say "there is no finite length". $\sqrt{3}$ is certainly finite. Asking whether you can accurately measure something is far different from asking whether something is finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its all about how you define your units while measuring.

I can always plot √3 on a real number line . Let the length of this plot from 0 be defined as 1 unit. Then volume of the box is 1 unit^3.

This same volume when expressed in the units of centimeters, the volume is
 3√3 cm^3.

Answer (score 3):

If the real numbers are defined,
then the volume is defined
and it is $3^{3/2} = 3\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Makes sense. But how do I measure √3.

Comment: @DinguSagar you don't, but questions about measuring are not about mathematics. Anyway, any measuring instrument only has finite precision, so even if the length of the box is exactly $\sqrt{3}$ meters, you would never know. But at the same time, you would also never know if it was exactly $0.3$ meters either. In any case, questions about precision of measurements aren't mathematical and are perhaps better suited to physics.SE

Comment: You can't measure $\sqrt{3}$ but you can construct it: a right triangle with hypotenuse 2 and leg 1 has the other leg $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @DinguSagar `how do I measure √3` How do you "measure" in general? The number value depends on the unit you choose. A length could be an integer if you measure it in meters, but an irrational (actually, transcendental) if you measure it in [parsecs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsec). However, intrinsic properties such as the volume of the cube is the cube (3rd power) of its side hold true regardless of the units.

Comment: Thanks ....Intuitively getting something now :)

Answer (score 0):

As your second question asks "is the area of a square paper with $\sqrt2$ definite"

Consider:-

If you have a square of side 2 units , then what is the length of its diagonal? Is length of diagonal you got is precise(definite)?

By answering above questions you can answer your question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be muddling physics with mathematics.

Let a cube have edge length $a$, a real number. Then its volume is $a^3$, irregardless of the rationality of $a$.

In the mathematical description, we're not concerned about the physicality of these objects. From a physical perspective, it is impossible to measure any length exactly. This is not a limitation of our tools, but a fundamental consequence related to the [Heisenberg uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle).

Comment: But I am always able to measure 2 or 3.

Comment: @DinguSagar: It is only an approximation, to be truthful.